# Can page-object be used outside of Cucumber?

Tags: page-object-gem

I am trying to understand what exactly ties the page-object gem to Cucumber.

The page factory is exposed to Cucumbers world which allows the use of on / visit in steps, but this seems to be something that can be exposed without Cucumber.

The @browser variable which page-object relies on is created in a before_suite or before_scenario context in Cucumber but this can also be created without Cucumber.

Is there anything actually tying this gem to Cucumber?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Page-object gem can be used outside of Cucumber.

Here is an example how you can use it with RSpec.

$ tree

```
├── Gemfile
├── spec
│   ├── my_app
│   │   └── search_spec.rb
│   ├── pages
│   │   ├── article_page.rb
│   │   └── index_page.rb
│   └── spec_helper.rb
```

Gemfile

```rb
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'rspec'
gem 'page-object'
```

spec_helper.rb

```rb
require 'page-object'

Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/pages/*_page.rb"].each { |file| require file }

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include PageObject::PageFactory

  config.before do
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
  end

  config.after do
    @browser.close
  end
end
```

search_spec.rb

```rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'Search field' do
  it 'searches an article' do
    visit(IndexPage) do |page|
      page.search = 'Ruby'
      page.submit_search
    end

    expect(on(ArticlePage).main_header).to eq('Ruby')
  end
end
```

article_page.rb

```rb
class ArticlePage
  include PageObject

  h1(:main_header)
end
```

index_page.rb

```rb
class IndexPage
  include PageObject

  page_url 'https://www.wikipedia.org'

  text_field(:search, id: 'searchInput')
  button(:submit_search)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned on rubygems.org [PageObject gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/page-object/versions/1.1.1) has only development dependency on Cucumber. It doesnt need cucumber for implementation. A precise explanation of difference between runtime and development dependencies is given [here](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/).

For execution purposes Cucumber looks for step definitions. Passing Page Factory to World adds the PageObject capabilities to Cucumber. The only thing that I can think of tying PageObject to Cucumber are its unit tests. Evmorov has already given a great solution for it to work with Rspec alone.